# What’s wrong with my question

Tags: support

I don’t know what is so wrong about my question:

[How to change the order between...](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63247/how-to-change-the-order-between-logged-in-as-content-and-submit-button)

that I got a downvote for that. I’ve wrote to the Stack Exchange Team and they recommended me to ask about this action in the Meta Forum.

Maybe someone could help me out?

Thx!

Best,

Nitzki

Comment: You ask because of **one** downvote? Why?

Comment: I don’t care about the downvote so much. I’d rather wanted to know, how I could improve my question, because I want to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

1. It's not clear from reading your question what is it about. If I understand right (and completely not sure I am), it is about `comment_form()` function however other than tag you don't actually say it explicitly.
2. Your code example seems to be incomplete (ripped out of somewhere) and formatted as one line is pretty much unreadable.
3. Questions about moving something around are often borderline pure CSS (which is out of scope for the site). Try to include screenshot or fragment of generated page source to better explain what changes you want to make and why.